# jar as jboss module: dependencies

Tags: java, jar, jboss7.x, war

I have a question about JBoss modules dependencies vs war dependencies.
I have an **app.war**; its webinf/lib directory contains a **myLib.jar** **only**. In this configuration everything works fine.

Now I have to move mylib.jar outside the war, so I put it into a JBoss module and added it to module.xml; I also added it to the deployment-structure.xml file in the war. 
In this new configuration my app.war finds succesfully the external myLib.jar **but now myLib.jar cannot find its dependencies anymore**.
Specifically it doesn't find **rowset.jar** as I get this exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/rowset/CachedRowSetImpl
```

Why can’t myLib.jar see all the libs it used to see when it was deployed inside the war? Do I have to create a JBoss module with myLib dependencies?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modules must have their own dependencies explicitly declared in the `modules.xml`. A Module cannot access jars that are part of a deployment.

Comment: Ok. A question about modules scope: my app.war can see all modules or just those I've explicitly declared in the war file jboss-deployment-structure.xml?

Comment: hmm not sure. But even if it's not required, at least it's good practice to still declare it.