# Can a JBoss module depend on a jar

Tags: java, jar, jboss

I have made a jboss module to provide some base code. I want to log out some data when this module is deployed to jboss. I can achieve this by creating a simple class, like so:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public MyClass {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("I am in here");
    }

}
```

The above initi method works, and is initiated correctly. Note, the module above is a jar.

However, when I extract the above code into its own project, and add the compiled jar as a dependency to the same module, the code is never executed. Conversely, if I add it to war deployable, it works as expected. i.e Maven dependency

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.myModuleCommon</groupId>
     <artifactId>moduleCommon</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I have looked at the documentation [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODULES/Introduction) and examined this stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25913946/jar-as-jboss-module-dependencies) tho I am unsure if that is the reason I cannot have a jar module depend on another jar.

My question then is, why does my extracted code not get invoked during startup (i.e The class above) when used as a dependency for a  module, but works both as an internal class or as an dependency in a war deployable?

i.e In my sample war file, I can see the extracted dependency under WEB-INF/lib. However, in my jar module, there is nothing in the Manifest file that denotes that this dependency is being used. Maybe this is part of the problem, where there might be some alternate way to specify a dependency in a module.

Comment: What does that mean, "used as an external jar" ? The EJB is only going to work when deployed in an environment that supports EJBs. Which is either as part of a war or an ear on a JEE container. EDIT: oh wait, it just clicked. You mean if you package it in a separate jar and put that in the war, it won't work. But when deployed as a class in WEB-INF/classes, it works

Comment: @Gimby right, so if i extract the aboce code into a seperate project, and add it as a dependency in my module, it does not get executed. However, if I keep it as a class in the module code, it works.

Comment: When you package in a separate jar, is the jar actually present in WEB-INF/lib when deployed to the server and is your class actually inside the jar? (simplest answer for things not working is things not actually physically existing).

Comment: @Gimby none of my modules have a WEB-INF/lib folder. The separate jar doesn't either. However, the separate jar does contain the created class above

Comment: You're only looking at the code in your IDE right? You're not looking at the war as deployed to the server.

Comment: @Gimby my server only has a jar file that I deployed. my local ide does not contian that folder. I do have a META-INF folder for this module, but the dependency is not shown in the MANIFEST.MF file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the documentation in the question, I believe that the correct answer is that module dependencies need to be explicitly added in the MANIFEST  or jboss-deplyment-structure.xml file. [Here is an article that shows how this can be done](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Implicit+module+dependencies+for+deployments)

i.e Using maven:

```
<configuration>
   <archive>
      <manifestEntries>
         <Dependencies>com.something.dependency</Dependencies>
      </manifestEntries>
   </archive>
</configuration>
```

i.e Using jboss xml file

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
   <deployment>
      <dependencies>
         <module name="com.something.dependency" />
      </dependencies>
   </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```